# primefaces autocomplete select in selenium

Tags: selenium

how to select a list of element in aauto complete text box.i tried this code but im unable to select a list of element which popus up from autocomplete text box

```
 'List<WebElement> optionsToSelect =
              autoOptions.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@id='form:mat_panel']/ul"));
              System.out.println(optionsToSelect); for(WebElement option :
              optionsToSelect){ System.out.println(option);
              if(option.getText().equals(textToSelect)) {
              System.out.println("Trying to select: "+textToSelect);
              option.click(); break; } }'
```

Html code
[image: screen with html snap]

Comment: Shared screenshot show textbox html content, could you share HTML which showing list of elements associated with this text box as well..

Comment: And could you tell what is the problem with your tried code?? Is there any exception or something other reason for failure??

Comment: i didnt get any exception .Testing is passing without any Exception.but the autocorrect value is not selecting....

Comment: Make sure you able to print the options text from list on using this line `System.out.println(option.getText())` on your code